# VBA: Creating a class property that is an array of dictionaries

Tags: vba, class, dictionary, object, properties

In Microsoft Excel VBA I need to create a class that has two properties, "Name" and "Holdings".  "Name" is just a string so the code for that is easy.  But I need "Holdings" to be a variable length array containing dictionary objects.  So this is what I wrote:

```
Private mName As String
Private mHoldings() As Scripting.Dictionary

Public Property Let Name(vName As String)
      mName = vName
End Property
 
Public Property Get Name() As String
      Name = mName
End Property
 
Public Property Set Holdings(vHoldings() As Scripting.Dictionary)
      Set mHoldings = vHoldings
End Property
 
Public Property Get Holdings() As Scripting.Dictionary
      Set Holdings = mHoldings
End Property
```

When I try to compile it gives me this error:
"Definitions of property procedures for the same property are inconsistent, or property procedure has an optional parameter, a ParamArray, or an invalide Set final parameter.

What I doing wrong?

Comment: See  https://stackoverflow.com/a/48172930/478884 and maybe  https://stackoverflow.com/a/24367842/478884

Comment: If you don't insist on using arrays, which are kind of `difficult` in VBA then it would probably be more useful to create two more classes. One named `Holding` and second named `Holdings`. `Holding` will encapsulate the dictionary and `Holdings` will be a [custom collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58454735/making-custom-collection-in-excel-vba) of `Holding`.